# Pretty / GUI formatting for the nosetests.xml xUnit report?

Tags: selenium, unit-tests

Is there a simple tool that will generate pie charts or otherwise "pretty", graphical output based on the .xml file that nose outputs with the `--with-xunit` switch?

I tried googling around for one but didn't have any luck. I think TestNG will do it? But it sounded like a lot of setup required.

Comment: has anyone managed to deal with the above kind of scenario through an xml editor? I was looking at xmlblueprint but not sure how good he parser is, [Liquid XML Editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-editor.aspx) looks pretty good though.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a simple tool for doing what you asked, but I offer the following alternative.  I think this breaks down into two problems: converting an XML file to something more amenable to a graphing package (for example, a CSV file), and then instructing the graphing package to convert the data into a graph.

There are a variety of methods for extracting data from an XML file; your choice will depend on your personal preferences and your programming skills.  For example, I believe nose is a python tool; you could use one of the Python XML parsers to extract the data and produce a CSV file.  Depending on the XML file's format, and if it is convenient for you to use Unix command line tools, you may be able to extract the data using awk, grep, and sed.

If you Google for "convert csv to graph", you will find many tools for graphing your data.